# Installation of Ubuntu 14.04 failure

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows legacy mode. Now Windows is lost and Ubuntu could not be used. When I switch on my machine  no boot device found appears on screen. What can I do to install and use only Ubuntu?

Comment: The 14.04 will reach end of life in 2 months. I suggest a fresh install of a newer LTS release like 16.04, 18.04.

Comment: you could reuse your install media, boot into a desktop, run `gparted` and check if it finds any hdd and if your partitions (windows along with linux) are still there. Than you could try boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair - i expect your bootloader to be broken, thats what the message might indicate